# Docker image updates with docker load, how?

Tags: docker

It seems like Docker does not overwrite the old image when I update and load a new one with docker load.

Personally I would

```sh
docker remove -f myimage;
docker load < myimage.tar.gz;
```

However that's not the recommended way to do, if understand it properly.

Therfore I am wondering if I add new images over the course of new upgrade cycles, how does Docker select the appropriate version? And won't the Docker host get cluttered with versions?

Comment: If you don't `docker rmi` the old image, and you `docker load` a new image with the same tag, the old image should still be present but marked as `<none>` in the `docker images` listing.  You might find a Docker registry a little easier to use and manage long-term than `docker save`/`docker load` (especially if you have a lot of questions about the manual image copy process).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you very much for your explanation. I don't feel comfortable using docker hub at the moment. I don't know how long they are going to be around. I'll definitely make use of them, once I know how to substitute their service, in case of an emergency.

Comment: Most of the public cloud providers have their own image-registry offerings; GitHub has one these days; or you can run your own.  It doesn't have to be Docker Hub.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @DavidMaze. I appreciate it a lot.